# Check if a value exists on a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list: `object = [x, y, type, name]`

I want to add it to an array, if it's not already added:

```
if not object in world[int(room)]:
   world[int(room)].append(object)
```

This worked very nice without the x and y coordinates.

What I want to do is to now compare the lists without x and y. Just by type and name.

Something like 
`if not object[2:] in world[room][2:]`

Comment: First, `object` is part of the Python built-in namespace, so your use of that same namespace for different, custom objects is confusing and not best practice. Second, could you show more code? Is `world` a dict or a list? What is `room`? Why are you coercing it to an `int`? Can you show a sample (e.g. the first two elements) of the object of which you speak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `generator` of `lists` made from the elements from index `2` onwards for each item in the  `world[int(room)]` list:

```
if not object[2:] in (i[2:] for i in world[int(room)]):
   world[int(room)].append(object)
```

---

*N.b. you should also not use `object` as it is an identifier that refers to a built-in type, so by using it as a variable name, you are overriding it.*

Comment: Thanks @Joe Iddon. At first glance, that worked.  The "object" ... yea ... its quite a rookie error. As i came from a split of something called objects... i named it object.

Comment: @blacksite, thank you also. Fyi, "room" is a String and comes from a topic as a String.i could cast it before ... but didnt. world is a list of rooms known by the explorer bot. in each room, there another list of objects (object) recognized by the bot. it stores [x_pos, y_pos. type, name]. that why i needed to compare only type and name for each room, cause the bot can "spot" the same object from different (x,y). Again, thank you all. this is my first experience in python and ... is very, very nice. Although some sintax looks strange for old school (C, Delphy) developers.